# New Users Chat by Invitation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users, chat, privileges

I've had occasion recently (I've only been here two weeks, but whatever...) to answer a new member's question, only to quickly realize that the individual's misconceptions or lack of knowledge exceed what I feel comfortable covering in answers or comments, and that an extended chat is called for, but the questioner lacks the rank to join in a chat.

Would there be merit in allowing a user with chat privilege to create a chat and then invite an unprivileged user to participate? I appreciate the sense in not allowing new users to *create* new chats, but prohibiting them outright seems a bit stricter than necessary.

(Alternately, is this a facility which already exists but which I have not yet discovered?)

Comment: 'I've only been here two weeks' - I can tell.  If you had more experience here, you would not be asking to cater for an all-you-can-drink buffet for the vampires:)

Comment: That does look like the answer to my question. Maybe this should be documented somewhere?